# Word VSTO CustomXMLNode.SelectSingleNode fails after Office upgrade

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, vsto, office-addins

A word vsto addin fails with exception on calling CustomXMLNode.SelectSingleNode.

The addin runs fine with word 2007 - 2013, but on version 2016 it fails with Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'ns0'.

[image: visual studio screenshot]

I've made a workaround navigating the XML without the use of xpath and these methods, but still need to figure out how to solve this issue.

```
            var xPathExpression = String.Format(
                    "{0}:{1}[1]",
                    customXml.NamespaceManager.LookupPrefix(xmlRef.DefaultNamespace),
                    xmlRef.ElementNames.DisplayText.LocalName);
            groupMembers[j].SelectSingleNode(xPathExpression);
```

The resulting xPathExpression is

```
ns0:DisplayText[1]
```

The xml looks like this:

```
<MyXmlTest xmlns="http://www.myxmltest.com/document">
  <Ribbon visible="true">
    <Group name="xmlProperties">Document Properties</Group>
    <Group name="xmlActions">Other Properties</Group>
  </Ribbon>
  <DocumentList>
    <Document>
      <Properties ribbonLabel="Hello World Menu">
        <Property name="helloWorld">
          <RibbonButton groupName="xmlActions">
            <DisplayText>Hello World</DisplayText>
            <PlaceholderText>N/A</PlaceholderText>
            <Tooltip>Some text goes here.</Tooltip>
          </RibbonButton>
          <Content/>
        </Property>         
        <Property name="title">
          <RibbonButton groupName="xmlProperties">
            <DisplayText>Hello World Text</DisplayText>
            <PlaceholderText>N/A</PlaceholderText>
            <Tooltip>Insert Hello World in Document</Tooltip>
          </RibbonButton>
          <Content>Testing</Content>       
        </Property>
      </Properties>
    </Document>
  </DocumentList>
</MyXmlTest>
```

Comment: As workaround, maybe you can try to ignore namespaces by using `local-name()` : `*[local-name()='DisplayText'][1]`

Comment: That works!!! I tried something similar earlier which selected the first node in the document, not the first from current node, but probably not the same syntax. Thank you.  If you add a answer, I'll mark it as answered

Comment: You probably tried `//*[local-name()='DisplayText'][1]` earlier. Starting the XPath with `/` would make it search from the document root..

Comment: You are absolutely correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, to execute XPath containing namespace prefix you need to [pass along namespace manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b(v=vs.110).aspx) containing the prefix-URI mapping. Since this option isn't available in your case, as a workaround, you can try to ignore namespaces by using `local-name()` :

```
*[local-name()='DisplayText'][1]
```

Comment: There is no overloaded SelectSingleNode method accepting namespacemanager. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862077(v=office.15).aspx   customXml is of CustomXMLPart class